# Reporting base levels of categorical predictors in regression summary

Tags: r, regression

Suppose that `myGlm` is a `glm` object in R.

`summary(myGlm)` displays coefficient estimates for all of the interesting dummy variables. However, I often don't know what the reference levels are since I have many nominal factors with many levels. Does there exist a method to output the base levels along with the estimates?

(Apologies in advance if this should really be in SO, not sure where to put it)

edit to include example

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
print(d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
summary(glm.D93)

Call:
glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())

Deviance Residuals: 
       1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9  
-0.67125   0.96272  -0.16965  -0.21999  -0.95552   1.04939   0.84715  -0.09167  -0.96656  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.045e+00  1.709e-01  17.815   <2e-16 ***
outcome2    -4.543e-01  2.022e-01  -2.247   0.0246 *  
outcome3    -2.930e-01  1.927e-01  -1.520   0.1285    
treatment2   8.717e-16  2.000e-01   0.000   1.0000    
treatment3   4.557e-16  2.000e-01   0.000   1.0000    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here we can see outcome2, outcome3, but not outcome1, which I'd like to see in the output (with an estimate of 0 or blank). In this particular example, it's obvious that the base level is outcome1, but if I'm working with variables such as Country with levels {USA, Mexico, Canada, ...} I might not remember which one comes first and is omitted.

example output I'm looking for:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.045e+00  1.709e-01  17.815   <2e-16 ***
outcome1     0          NA         NA      NA
outcome2    -4.543e-01  2.022e-01  -2.247   0.0246 *  
outcome3    -2.930e-01  1.927e-01  -1.520   0.1285 
treatment1   0          NA         NA       NA   
treatment2   8.717e-16  2.000e-01   0.000   1.0000    
treatment3   4.557e-16  2.000e-01   0.000   1.0000
```

Comment: Not sure but ?     dummy.coef(model)

Comment: Do you simply want to know which level of your factor is the base level, or how to find the mean value of y associated with each level of a factor? Are you wondering how these things work logically, or what the function call is in R?

Comment: edited to give example. it seems like i can quickly get the info I need using dummy.coef as charles suggests, but some hacking is needed to get the std errors/z values along with it